# SwiftUI - Binding in child view is not updating

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have two views currently. A parent view with a List of `Pledges' (basically just a struct with a string and an image), and a child view which displays a confirmation of the pledge you selected from the list.

I have a state variable in the parent and in the child, a binding to this variable. However, the List item selected isn't always the one which is passed to the child confirmation view. It's as if the child binding variable isn't updating when a list item is selected.

does anyone have any ideas? thanks

Parent view:

```
    
    let worstArea: String
    @State var selection: String? = nil
    var body: some View {
        let pledgeList = getListOfPledges(worstArea: worstArea)
                    List(pledgeList) {
                        pledge in
                        Spacer()
                        NavigationLink(destination: PleadeConfirmation(pledgePicked: $selection)) {
                            pledgeRow(pledge: pledge, worstArea: worstArea).onTapGesture {
                                selection = pledge.description
                            }

                    }
              }
    
        
    }
```

Child view (PleadeConfirmation):

```
struct PleadeConfirmation: View {
    @Binding var pledgePicked:String?
    var body: some View {
        Text("Commit to pledge: \(pledgePicked ?? "none selected")").multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        
 }
        
}
```

The pledgePicked variable in child is the one in question which doesn't always reflect the list value being selected

Comment: You are creating a list of navigation links but all destination views uses the same variable, this can't be right. I would expect something like `NavigationLink(destination: PleadeConfirmation(pledgePicked: pledge.description))` and in the child view you don't need `@Binding` if you are not changing the variable

Comment: There is a list of pledges and depending on which list item is selected, the selection variable should update. This is the variable which is bound to the child...at least that's what should happen. They're supposed to all go to the same place, but just have a different value reflected. I didn't want to have to surround each `Pledge' with a separate Navigation Link when they're supposed to all go to the same view. Let me try out your suggestion though

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks, I think your answer works!